# find all local maximum from the Mat of image in openCv

Tags: opencv, matrix, max

I'm currently trying to localise barcode and i want get pixel information of etch local maximum in Mat image.Here is the code

```
    /**Applying Canny**/ 
  Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mGray, 80, 90);
  Imgproc.threshold(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU, 255, CvType.CV_8UC1);
  Size ksize=new Size(31,31);
  Imgproc.blur(mGray, mGray, ksize);
```

list of the local maximum = max(mGray)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean return the maximum of `mGray`?
maybe you can use [cvMinMaxLoc](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvminmaxloc)

Comment: thanks shihongzhi but I can't find this function in openCV library for java

Comment: Hey :) The link you posted is down now, would you mind summarizing what you meant in the answer? Thanks :)